# Efficient DataFrame Grouping for Condensing Rows Based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I'm aiming to group the rows based on the 'Chromosome', 'Start', and 'End' columns and then condense the corresponding 'Start1', 'End1',main_category columns into lists. Then I want to do the same thing but with the Chromosome, Start1, End1 cols. Basically, there should not be duplicates across the 'Chromosome', 'Start', and 'End' columns OR 'Chromosome', 'Start1', 'End1', 'main_category' columns. Here's a sample input/output:

Here is a subset of my dataset:

```
Chromosome  Start   End     Start1  End1    main_category
    chr1    2584125 2584533 2584094 2584437 Enhancer
    chr1    2584125 2584533 2584200 2584401 Promoter
    chr1    3069168 3069296 3066400 3074201 Promoter
    chr1    3069168 3069296 3069019 3069238 Promoter
    chr1    3069168 3069296 3069272 3069608 Enhancer
    chr1    3186125 3186474 3186069 3186414 Enhancer
    chr1    3244087 3244137 3244018 3244334 Enhancer
    chr1    3244555 3244666 3244660 3244666 Promoter
    chr1    3244755 3244966 3244660 3244666 Promoter
```

```
Chromosome  Start   End     Start1             End1             main_category
chr1    2584125 2584533 [2584094,2584200] [2584437,2584401] [Enhancer,Promoter]
chr1    3069168 3069296 [3066400,3069019,3069272][3074201,3069238,3069608][Promoter,Promoter,Enhancer]
chr1    3186125 3186474 3186069 3186414 Enhancer
chr1    3244087 3244137 3244018 3244334 Enhancer
chr1    [3244555,3244755] [3244666,3244966] 3244660 3244666 Promoter
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. It fills the dataset with NaNs and expands the dataset a lot:

```
condensed_df = df.groupby(['Chromosome', 'Start', 'End']).agg(
    {
        'main_category': lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)),
        'Start1': lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)),                                  
        'End1': lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x))
    }
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Chromosome', 'Start', 'End']).agg(list)` or maybe better fit to the expected output: `df.groupby(['Chromosome', 'Start', 'End']).agg(lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x)`

Answer (score -1):

Looping through the grouped df, and then create a new df might make the results look better:

```
rows = []
for (chromosome, start, end), g in df.groupby(['Chromosome', 'Start', 'End']):
    start_element = list(g['Start1'])
    end_element = list(g['End1'])
    main_category = list(g['main_category'])
    row = {'Chromosome': chromosome,
           'Start': start,
           'End': end,
           'start_element': start_element,
           'end_element': end_element,
           'main_category': main_category}
    rows.append(row)
condensed_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

[image]